# Why are there fields related to sampling in the latencyTracking record

Tags: google-analytics

The fields named domLatencyMetricsSample, pageLoadSample, speedMetricsSample, and userTimingSample in the latencyTracking record of the [Bigquery Exports Schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719) (for Google Analytics) seem unnecessary since the export should contain *all* hits and not a sample of hits.

Is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API

Answer (score 0):

Because they are still sampled in the BigQuery export:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ga-bigquery-developers/1KomNbPjdMw/XwoTkUCTBgAJ